# Why doesn't Firefox trigger UAC notification on Windows 7?

Tags: firefox, uac, c#

I have a C# (WPF) application (my own creation) that needs to open a port on the computer. This means that it requires administrative privileges to run. The app is currently unsigned and every time I run it it brings up the UAC prompt inquiring whether I want to let this program from an unknown publisher make changes to my computer.

I was wondering why Firefox doesn't trigger a UAC warning. After all, it too must open a port to be able to access the internet. Is it because Firefox is a native app?

Comment: Are you sure the UAC prompt is because your program is trying to "open a port" and not because it's doing something else?  If you disable the firewall, do you still get a UAC prompt?

Comment: @techie007: The UAC prompt is because I've set `requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"` in the app manifest. I had to do this because I use `ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint` to open the port, and this call fails unless the app is run as administrator.

Comment: Ahhhh.. Have you seen this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/f1a9a996-5c33-4299-9388-df7aef487578 ?   Perhaps you're better off asking "how to use ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint without impersonation" over at StackOverflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program opens a port for **listening** for incoming connections. Firefox does not do that – it **connects** to a server.

Outgoing connections *do* use an ephemeral port locally too, but it is opened implicitly for just that specific connection (see [*stateful firewall*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall)).